# Matplotlib: use a colormap to show concentration of a process around its mean

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains 100 realization of a given process, observed at 10 different dates (all realization start from the same point at date 0).
Such a DataFrame can be generated with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nbDates = 10
nbPaths = 100
rnd = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=nbPaths*nbDates).reshape(nbDates,nbPaths)
sim = dict()
sim[0] = [100.0] * nbPaths
for t in range(nbDates):
    sim[t+1] = sim[t] + rnd[t]
sim = pd.DataFrame(sim)
```

Now I know I can plot the 100 paths contained in the DataFrame like this

```
sim.T.plot(legend=False)
```

and obtain a graph like this:

[image]

But what I actually would like to do is plot the minimum and maximum of my process at every date, and color the area between the two extremas with a color map that would reflect the concentration of the paths in the plot (so for instance red around the mean and gradually cooler as we go to the extremes).

I have looked at using colormaps to achieve this, but I have not managed it yet. If anyone knows a straightforward way to do that it would be very helpful.

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you give an example of a plot? Maybe have a look at http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html. There are a lot of examples, and clicking on any of them will get you the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (albeit probably not in the most elegant way) by first making a contour plot of your "concentration" with `contourf`, then making a line plot of your max & min, and finally using the `fill_between` method to cover up the unwanted portions of the contour plot. The proper way to do this however would be to mask the array in the contour plot but I don't quite have the time to figure that out right now (have a look at [numpy mask array options](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) and take a stab at it). You'd want to mask the array to only show up between your max and min values.

Here's an example using `fill_between` instead of masking the array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## Your simulation code here ##

# Extract max, min, and mean values for each x coordinate
minimums = np.array(sim.min())
maximums = np.array(sim.max())
means = np.array(sim.mean())

x = np.array(sim.min().index)
y = np.arange(90,111)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Insert your calculation for "concentration" in the line below
Z = (maximums[X] - minimums[X]) * Y // 100

# set up axes with matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot contour, you'll want to change the levels
# depending on the range of values in your "concentration"
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=np.arange(0,20,.1), cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))

# Plot min, max, and mean
ax.plot(x, minimums, c='k')
ax.plot(x, maximums, c='k')
ax.plot(x, means, c='k', lw=2)

# Fill space outside min and max with white
ax.fill_between(x, maximums, 110, color='w')
ax.fill_between(x, 90, minimums, color='w')
```

This should produce the following output:

[image: Colormap fill between]

You can choose your own function for calculating the "concentration" to get the kind of fill pattern you want. The one in the code above is intended to show how you can have it depend on both the X and Y position in the plot. Good luck!